# How can I stop Ubuntu GUI apps like Synapic and Shutdown from asking root password

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I know I can add 'NOPASSWD' to '/usr/sudoers'. But it only works with command line commands such as `sudo vim ~/test`. How can I stop GUI applications like when shutting down the computer?

Comment: Is "Shutdown" a gui application? You are using Synaptic only now and then to configure the system, not in your daily work. Leave the password there. It is good practice.

Comment: Shutdown means shutdown computer or logout from the GNOME GUI. I know it's more secure and good practice. But It is in a test enviroment within the VM. I think leave it to user's decision is more practical.

Comment: Is this a server? A desktop system does not require root password to shut down.